# Android - Problems while fetching info from sql database

Tags: android, sqlite

Greetings overflow community.

I'm still a newbie for Android develpment, so please bear with me. 
I'm sorry if this is already in another thread. I couldn't find anything related.

By following a huge amount of tutorials for the last 2 weeks, i've been trying to create an app that register reports on a database with the 4 tables below. They're created inside the app

1 -  User table

2 -  Project table

3 -  type 1 project table

4 -  type 2 project table

My problem is in the login screen. I'm trying to search my username/password fields in the user table in order to confirm user access.

If my username/password entry is found inside the table, it will search on the project table for all the projects that this user already created and return it on a list on the next activity. When clicking the login button, it should the app freezes and crashes after some time. Could you guys lend me a hand to understand whats going on with it?

The only thing my logcat shows are that I have leaks in some SQLiteConnections, which I don't know how to solve... My database class is kinda huge atm so if you guys need anything to be posted in order to understand the problem, I'll post later.

What are gservices.db and networkstatistics.sqlite?

```
09-26 14:32:40.266 2022-2035/com.google.process.gapps W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gsf/databases/gservices.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
09-26 14:33:05.120 2210-2222/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/networkstatistics.sqlite' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

The method that freezes the app is the following:

```
public boolean search_access(user user){
    String [] tabela_user = new String[]{"username","password"};
    String compare_user = "COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = ?";
    String [] whereargs = new String[]{user.getUsername()}


    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, tabela_user, compare_user, null, null, null, null );

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        if(cursor.getString(0).equals(user.getPassword())) {
            MainActivity.acesso = true;
        } else{
            CharSequence text = "Incorrect Username/Password!!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(null, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            MainActivity.acesso = false;
        }
    }
    return MainActivity.acesso;
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.relatoriodeobras.projeto_db.busca_acesso(projeto_db.java:177)(which is the cursor line)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should move database access to a new thread. CursorLoader can help with this.

Comment: `usuario.getUsername() == username_login` <= what is it? That is not how we compare strings in java ... also why are you not ask db for count of the user with given name and password instead iterating whole table and compare? *the app freezes and crashes after some time* <= prolly ANR

Comment: Okay @Code-Apprentice, I'll try it and look for CursorLoader. Thanks!

Comment: As I said @Selvin, I'm new to this whole thing and been trying to figure it out on my own. Okay. I'll look for java string comparison in order to fix that. About that db for count, could you please point some tutorial/example for me to follow? I want to understand it. About ANR, how do I investigate it if it doesn't show any errors in logcat? DDMS? Thank you both.

Comment: What line causes the new NPE?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, tabela_user, compare_user, null, null, null, null );`

Comment: `db` is `null`. Where do you declare it? You also need to initialize it somewhere.

Comment: Another tidbit: it looks like you have a static variable named `acesso` in `MainActivity`. This violates several object oriented concepts. Depending on where you call `search_access()`, you should just be able to return `true` or `false` directly without using this variable at all.

Comment: Done. search_access() is only returning true or false. db is being initialized along with the other variables on the beginning of database class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really too complex for this kind of operation.
Try to use this code:

```
String userName = user.getUsername();


Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, new String[]{COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD}, "COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = ?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null, null, null);

if(cursor.moveToFirst)
{
 if(cursor.getString(0).equals(user.getPassword())) MainActivity.acesso = true;
 else{
                        CharSequence text = "Incorrect Username/Password!!";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(null, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                        MainActivity.acesso = false;
                }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, use query().

Comment: I'm getting null object reference error at 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])'... Does it mean that it's not receiving any username at all?

Comment: Use if statement to check whether userName equals null. To can use Log.v() function to get the information in the consle.

Comment: userName is returning what's in the username EditText accordingly. So I guess the null refernce is the String[]

Comment: Edit you code in this way: `String sql = "SELECT " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " FROM " + TABLE_USER 
+ " WHERE COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = " + user.getUsername();
Cursor cursor = db.query(sql);`

Comment: Did as you said. "Cannot resolve method 'query(java.lang.String)'". I'm looking if I need to put any more parameters inside query.

Comment: So, here's what I did in a attempt to re-order everything: `String [] tabela_user = new String[]{"username","password"};` | `String compare_user = "COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = " + user.getUsername();` | `Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, tabela_user, compare_user, null, null, null, null );` | It's returning null object reference error.

Comment: `cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, new String[]{COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD},  "COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = ?", new String[]{user.getUsername()}, null, null, null, null, null);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `query()`  instead of `rawQuery()`.  It has parameters which allow you to filter the results.  This is similar to a `WHERE` clause in a SQ query.

**Update:**

Instead of

```
String compare_user = "COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = " + user.getUsername();
```

You should do

```
String compare_user = "COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = ?";
```

Then you need to provide the fourth parameter to `query()` as

```
String user_array = new String[]{user.getUsername()};
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, tabela_user, compare_user, user_array, null, null, null );
```

When you concatenate strings to build up a SQL query, you run the risk of a SQL injection attack. Using the `?` syntax instead will avoid this security flaw. Even if it isn't a big deal with your current app, this is a good habit to start now.

Comment: So, here's what I did in a attempt to re-order everything: `String [] tabela_user = new String[]{"username","password"};` | `String compare_user = "COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = " + user.getUsername();` | `Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, tabela_user, compare_user, null, null, null, null );` | It's gets a null object reference error.

Comment: @HextechEnthusiast Please edit your original question or post a new one so that you can provide code in a readable format.

Comment: @HextechEnthusiast `String compare_user = "COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = " + user.getUsername();` should be `String compare_user = "COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = ?";` in order to avoid SQL injection attacks. And then you need to provide the 4th parameter to `query()`.

Comment: Done. I edited my answer with the method reorganized @W.Kurek

Comment: Should I put user.getUsername() as whereargs?

Comment: @HextechEnthusiast `whereargs` is declared as `String[]`, so there's a little more to it. See my edit for details.

Comment: @HextechEnthusiast Of course, this doesn't solve the "null object reference" problem. Let's look into that further.

Comment: I did everything as mentioned and am still getting null object reference, guess I'll look for the variables.

Comment: I initialized db inside the method, using `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();` . Now i'm getting a new error: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: COLUMN_USER_USERNAME (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT usuaid, username, password FROM usuario WHERE COLUMN_USER_USERNAME = ?` I'm pointing my cursor to the wrong direction right?

Comment: @HextechEnthusiast please post a new question

Comment: Create a new topic all over again?

Comment: @HextechEnthusiast yes, each question here should address one issue. When that is addressed and resolved you should post a new question.